# PHP: Lock all MySQL tables in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I look all tables in a MySQL database in PHP?

Im sure there must be a way to do it, but cant seem to find any PHP functions to do the job.

Looking for something like this

```
lock_all_mysql_tables();
//.... calling some external functions which require db lock
unlock_all_mysql_tables();
```

Comment: You want us to know that you're using PHP right ? (title x 2 + tag)

Comment: @Chouchenos it's ironic that the solution will probably have nothing to do with PHP :)

Comment: yes,you can issue lock ... but it will lock for any queries as well ...

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is an absolute way of doing what you require but you can get a list of tables in the database...

MySQL:

```
SHOW tables
```

... then run a foreach loop on the results to lock/unlock each table.

Comment: can above changed to be a more efficient method?

Comment: @ajreal - You could maybe cache the table names to avoid the SQL query?

Answer (score 1):

There is a much easier way of locking all tables, but it entails 'abusing' the FLUSH command to lock all tables. Flushing your entire database means MySQL will reload its various internal caches, so this may not play well with large tables/databases.

I have only tried this with MyISAM tables, and I have heard people say this doesn't work properly for InnoDB tables, so be careful if your table type is not MyISAM.

Here's how to do it:

```
mysql_query("FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK");
   /* do stuff while entire database is locked */
mysql_query("UNLOCK TABLES");
```

If you use MySQL replication you can avoid syncing the FLUSH command to the slave server by changing the first query to:

```
mysql_query("FLUSH LOCAL TABLES WITH READ LOCK");
```

More info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/flush.html